Please break down the title of this song: 너무 아픈 사랑은 사랑이 아니었음을
The official translation of the title simply says: "It's not love if it hurts too much". I am not great at Korean, but the grammar structure of this sentence is very complicated to me. what does the 이었음을 means?

It is indeed a rather complicated phrase intended for poetic effect.  You wouldn't say it like this if you just wanted to get the point across.  The English translation you listed can be more simply phrased as 사랑이 너무 아프면 사랑이 아니다 or 너무 아픈 사랑은 사랑이 아니다.
It uses 사랑이 아니었음을 to imply both the past tense and how they are reminiscing or regretting after the fact.  If you break it down it goes like this:

사랑이 아니다 = It is not love.
사랑이 아니었다 = It was not love.
사랑이 아니었음 = (The fact) That it was not love.  (ㅁ or 음 on a verb stem creates a noun out of a verb)
사랑이 아니었음을 => 을 makes the whole phrase an objective case, so it suggests the speaker is thinking, reminiscing or doing whatever with the phrase, without specifying exactly what.

So 사랑이 아니었음을 is like an object of a verb which is not specified.  This creates a typical poetic effect of evoking something in the reader's mind.

Thanks, that was my intuition as well that it sounded like there was some regret (my parents are korean but im not), but the english title did not include any kind of feeling like that. So while there is not explicit "reminisce, regret" verb attached to the object "사랑이 아니었음을", we can imply there is one.
